# Static vector resize

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, resize, program-entry-point

I want to make a static vector in a class and I want to resize the vectors when they are created. I'm trying to do this in the constructor or in the main function. But I can't get it to work. The problem is that I can't call a function of the vector class on this way.
This is what I have now:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    static vector<int> testvec;
    test();
};

test::test() //Not static
{
    test::testvec.resize(0);    //Try 1
}

vector<int> test::testvec.resize(0); //Try 2

int main()
{
    test::testvec.resize(0); //Try 3
    test testclass;


    system("pause");
    return false;

}
```

I need to handle all the data on the vector in every object, that is why I want to make the vector static.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

Edit: grammer. Every method that I have tried gives a compile error.

Comment: Are you quite sure that your approach is really the best one? What if you need two independent groups of `test` objects at some point? A `shared_ptr` solution is probably better. (Static data can be fine sometimes, but it should be const or at least const-like; i.e. what one object does should never be able to cause a problem to the other objects, but resizing to 0 looks very trouble-prone.)

Comment: You need to forward declare static variables. In Try 1 there is no such thing a static constructor. In Try 2 you can't globally call methods of a static member. In Try 3 you are going to call `.resize(0)` twice. If you want to `clear()` in your constructor the static member probably isn't necessary. Also do not return `bool` from main and avoid `system` in general.

Comment: @AJG85: You need to *define* static variables (well, all variables, it is just that a non-extern declaration will also be a definition for most other type of variables). You *cannot forward declare* any variable.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yeah, my terminology is wrong there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a static member attribute you also need to *define* it:

```
class test {
public:
   static std::vector<int> v; // declaration
};
std::vector<int> test::v; // definition, note: no `static` here
```

You can optionally use a size to the constructor, which would avoid the need to resize:

```
std::vector<int> test::v( 10 ); // definition, create it with size==10
```

But you can still call resize from `main` if you prefer:

```
int main() { 
   test::v.resize( 20 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define static members in the implementation file.

like in main.cpp:

```
vector<int> Test::testvec;

int main() {
 ...
}
```

Comment: The `static` keyword in that context has a different meaning and should be removed.

Comment: Actually you would not repeat the `static` keyword in the forward declaration.

Comment: @AJG85: that is *not* a forward declaration, it is the *definition* of the static member. The line `static vector<int> testvec;` inside the class is just a *declaration* but not a definition.